# Modal not displaying with bulma css

Tags: html, css, bulma

I want to display a modal when a button is clicked but is not working. Here the code:

```
    <button class="button is-warning is-pulled-right" onclick="refs.modalEdicion.open()">
        <span>Editar</span>
    </button>
    <div class="modal" id="modalEdicion">
        <div class="modal-background"></div>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <p class="image is-4by3">
            <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png" alt="">
            </p>
        </div>
        <button class="modal-close is-large" aria-label="close"></button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this problem this week and I found this [link](https://siongui.github.io/2018/02/11/bulma-modal-with-javascript/). It contains Official (according to it) Bulma Modal Doc page's javascript code. I copied and reduced it by a line or two and it works for all bulma modals you will have in your code.

Note that this is pretty open code. Ali's answer is ideal route to follow but if you don't want to spend time writing codes for modals, then just copy this segment in your code.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

    // Modals

    var rootEl = document.documentElement;
    var allModals = getAll('.modal');
    var modalButtons = getAll('.modal-button');
    var modalCloses = getAll('.modal-background, .modal-close, .modal-card-head .delete, .modal-card-foot .button');

    if (modalButtons.length > 0) {
        modalButtons.forEach(function (el) {
            el.addEventListener('click', function () {
                var target = document.getElementById(el.dataset.target);
                rootEl.classList.add('is-clipped');
                target.classList.add('is-active');
            });
        });
    }

    if (modalCloses.length > 0) {
        modalCloses.forEach(function (el) {
            el.addEventListener('click', function () {
                closeModals();
            });
        });
    }

    document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
        var e = event || window.event;
        if (e.keyCode === 27) {
            closeModals();
        }
    });

    function closeModals() {
        rootEl.classList.remove('is-clipped');
        allModals.forEach(function (el) {
            el.classList.remove('is-active');
        });
    }

    // Functions

    function getAll(selector) {
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector), 0);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Before starting, easy way to open modal should be like this;

```
yourElem.classList.toggle('is-active')
```

In my project, I have many modals. So I didn't always want to use like above. Because of this, I have created a basic modal event listener. I know this isn't enough for you. Because there will be other situations to open and close modals.

In this case, you can open and close your modals even you can listen to show and close events.

I used [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#Creating_custom_events) Mozilla resource to create custom events. For example, you want to create two events called **modal:show** and **modal:close**. To make this, you should write some codes like below:

### On Show Event

```
var event = new Event('modal:show')

yourElem.dispatchEvent(event);
```

### On Close Event

```
var event = new Event('modal:close')

yourElem.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Now, we can listen to the above events.

### An Example to Listen to Show Event

```
yourElem.addEventListener('modal:show', function() {
    console.log("opened")
})
```

### An Example to Listen to Close Event

```
yourElem.addEventListener("modal:close", function() {
    console.log("closed")
})
```

We know how to open and close modal from easy way section. But sometimes users can click the modal background or **"X"** or **Cancel** buttons. If so, we need to handle these events. To make this we can use this code

```
var modalClose = yourelem.querySelectorAll("[data-bulma-modal='close'], 
  .modal-background")

modalClose.forEach(function(e) {
    e.addEventListener("click", function() {

        yourelem.classList.toggle('is-active')

            var event = new Event('modal:close')

            yourelem.dispatchEvent(event);
        })
})
```

That's all. We know how to open or close a Bulma modal. Even we can listen to their show and close events. Let's make it a little simpler

### Creating A BulmaModal Class

```
class BulmaModal {
    constructor(selector) {
        this.elem = document.querySelector(selector)
        this.close_data()
    }

    show() {
        this.elem.classList.toggle('is-active')
        this.on_show()
    }

    close() {
        this.elem.classList.toggle('is-active')
        this.on_close()
    }

    close_data() {
        var modalClose = this.elem.querySelectorAll("[data-bulma-modal='close'], 
        .modal-background")

        var that = this
        modalClose.forEach(function(e) {
            e.addEventListener("click", function() {

                that.elem.classList.toggle('is-active')

                var event = new Event('modal:close')

                that.elem.dispatchEvent(event);
            })
        })
    }

    on_show() {
        var event = new Event('modal:show')

        this.elem.dispatchEvent(event);
    }

    on_close() {
        var event = new Event('modal:close')

        this.elem.dispatchEvent(event);
    }

    addEventListener(event, callback) {
        this.elem.addEventListener(event, callback)
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
var btn = document.querySelector("#btn")
var mdl = new BulmaModal("#myModal")

btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    mdl.show()
})

mdl.addEventListener('modal:show', function() {
    console.log("opened")
})

mdl.addEventListener("modal:close", function() {
    console.log("closed")
})
```

### Let's look at this simple snippet

```js
class BulmaModal {
 constructor(selector) {
  this.elem = document.querySelector(selector)
  this.close_data()
 }
 
 show() {
  this.elem.classList.toggle('is-active')
  this.on_show()
 }
 
 close() {
  this.elem.classList.toggle('is-active')
  this.on_close()
 }
 
 close_data() {
  var modalClose = this.elem.querySelectorAll("[data-bulma-modal='close'], .modal-background")
  var that = this
  modalClose.forEach(function(e) {
   e.addEventListener("click", function() {
    
    that.elem.classList.toggle('is-active')

    var event = new Event('modal:close')

    that.elem.dispatchEvent(event);
   })
  })
 }
 
 on_show() {
  var event = new Event('modal:show')
 
  this.elem.dispatchEvent(event);
 }
 
 on_close() {
  var event = new Event('modal:close')
 
  this.elem.dispatchEvent(event);
 }
 
 addEventListener(event, callback) {
  this.elem.addEventListener(event, callback)
 }
}

var btn = document.querySelector("#btn")
var mdl = new BulmaModal("#myModal")

btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
 mdl.show()
})

mdl.addEventListener('modal:show', function() {
 console.log("opened")
})

mdl.addEventListener("modal:close", function() {
 console.log("closed")
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-background"></div>
  <div class="modal-card">
    <header class="modal-card-head">
      <p class="modal-card-title">Modal title</p>
      <button class="delete" aria-label="close" data-bulma-modal="close"></button>
    </header>
    <section class="modal-card-body">
      <p>There is something here</p>
    </section>
    <footer class="modal-card-foot">
      <button class="button is-success">Save changes</button>
      <button class="button" data-bulma-modal="close">Cancel</button>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="btn">Click active Modal</button>
```

I hope this answer will help Bulma newbies.

Answer (score 2):

Bulma CSS is a CSS only framework and all the javascript behaviour has to be written manually. That means for a modal all the CSS classes for hiding and showing the modal has been written and you have to just bind the events properly. If you visit the Modal doc page (https://bulma.io/documentation/components/modal/) you can see a `No Javascript` warning stating that

> Bulma does not include any JavaScript interaction. You will have to
>   implement the class toggle yourself.

Just define `refs.modalEdicion.open` function to add class `is-active` as per the doc and bind events on close button to remove the same CSS class. Optionally you might wish to bind the event to the overlay element as well if you want to dismiss modal by clicking the overlay.

Here is the desired implementation. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KRaqxG

Answer (score 0):

Okay first of all, you need to have posted your javascript and css for a relevant answer but I'll outline the way I do it.

You could implement like below:

```js
//One Modal
function OpenModal() {
    //Get element with Id= "modal"
    var modal = document.getElementById("modal");
    //Change style to display = "block"
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

//Multiple Modals
function OpenMore(n) {
    //Get elements with class="modal" into an array
    var modal = document.getElementsByClassName("modal");
    //Change style of modal number [n] to display = "block"
    modal[n].style.display = "block";
}

//This will close the modal once you click on it
window.onclick = function(event) {

    //For single modal
    var modal = document.getElementById("modal");
    //If the click was on the modal the modal style display = "none"
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    //For multiple modals
    var more = document.getElementsByClassName("modal");
    //i represents which modal. It will go through all modals
    for (var i = 0; i < more.length; i++) {
        //If the click was on the modal for one of the modals display = "none"
        //for all of them
        if (event.target == more[i]) {
            more[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.modal {
    display: none;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#modal {
    display: none;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.button {
    margin: 50px auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- For One Modal --> 
<button class="button" onclick="OpenModal()"> SingleModal </button>
<div id="modal"> hardidar </div>

<!-- For Multiple Modals -->
<button class="button" onclick="OpenMore(0)"> MultipleModal1 </button>
<div class="modal"> 1st Modal </div>

<button class="button" onclick="OpenMore(1)"> MultipleModal2 </button> 
<div class="modal"> 2nd Modal </div>
```

The idea is that the initial display of the modal per the css rules is `display: none` once you click on the button the Javascript method will run and change this to `display:block`

You could change this behavior to do quite a bit. You could toggle a class you could change the `transform: scale()` which is my personal preference.

The example is a working one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#your_id_button").click(function() {

     $("#id_modal").addClass("is-active"); // modal is open

   });

   $("#your_id_button_close").click(function() {

     $("#id_modal").removeClass("is-active"); // modal is close

   });

});`
```